# Windows 2008 Server Unable to activate with other methods

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-activation

I'm trying to activate windows 2008 server SP2 today since the activation trial is done.

I do not have an internet connection with this server so I can not activate online, and with the other servers in this farm I've been able to run the

slmgr -ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx 
and then it would open up the activate by phone method and we would just activate that way.

I say again, I don't have an internet connection so I can not do the online activate.

If I do the slui 4 it brings up the activation window but show me other ways to activate is still greyed out.

I've disabled the NIC on this Hyper-V server and I still can not get the other way to activate to show up...

Anyone have any ideas? This computer is one of my AD servers so.. it being in notification mode kind of sucks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure you have a valid product key installed by running `cscript slmgr.vbs /ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx`.
2. Run `cscript slmgr.vbs /dti` to get your Installation ID.
3. Call Microsoft activation Center for your country/region. Numbers are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/licensing/existing-customers/activation-centers.aspx).
4. Follow the usual phone call process dialing in the Installation ID from step 2 and note down the confirmation ID they give you.
5. Use `cscript slmgr.vbs /atp <confirmation id>`.
6. Use `cscript slmgr.vbs /ato` to attempt to activate.

Answer (score -1):

This MS Blog may assist.  [MS Activation Core Edition](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/02/02/how-to-activate-windows-server-2008-core-edition-with-mak-key-over-the-phone.aspx) adds some additional steps beyond what you indicated you tried.

This [Microsoft  VL Phone Numbers](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/activation-centers.aspx) list may get you in touch with the department that can assist directly if above fails